# Blind signature test fails

Tags: scala, digital-signature, public-key-encryption

In a code below I replicate the whole blind signature procedure: first client picks a message and blinds it, then server signs it, then client unblinds the server's signature and sends it back along with original message, and finally server checks if unblinded signature is valid.

The problem is that the result is false, unblinded signature does not match the original message and I don't understand why this is so. Can you please point out where I've made a mistake?

```
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.security.SecureRandom

import org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.SHA1Digest
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RSABlindingEngine
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RSAEngine
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.RSABlindingFactorGenerator
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.RSAKeyPairGenerator
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.RSABlindingParameters
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.RSAKeyGenerationParameters
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.RSAKeyParameters
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.PSSSigner

object ProvinGrounds {
    // Create a key pair for server
    val serverKeyPair = {
        val generator = new RSAKeyPairGenerator
        val bigInteger = new BigInteger("10001", 16)
        val params = new RSAKeyGenerationParameters(bigInteger, new SecureRandom, 2048, 80)

        generator.init(params)
        generator.generateKeyPair
    }   

    val public = serverKeyPair.getPublic.asInstanceOf[RSAKeyParameters]
  val message = "hello there".getBytes 

  // Generate a blinding factor
  val blindingFactorGenerator = new RSABlindingFactorGenerator
  blindingFactorGenerator.init(public)
  val blindingFactor = blindingFactorGenerator.generateBlindingFactor
  val blindingParams = new RSABlindingParameters(public, blindingFactor)

  // Blind the message and send it to server  
  val blindEngine = new RSABlindingEngine
  blindEngine.init(true, blindingParams)
  val blindedMessage = blindEngine.processBlock(message, 0, message.length)

  // Server signs a blinded message and sends a blind signature to client
  val serverSigner = new PSSSigner(new RSAEngine, new SHA1Digest, 20)
  serverSigner.init(true, serverKeyPair.getPrivate)
  serverSigner.update(blindedMessage, 0, blindedMessage.length)
  val blindedMessageSignature = serverSigner.generateSignature

  // Client unblinds a signature and sends it back to server along with original message
  val unBlindEngine = new RSABlindingEngine
  unBlindEngine.init(false, blindingParams)
  val unblindedMessageSignature = blindEngine.processBlock(blindedMessageSignature, 0, blindedMessageSignature.length)

  // Server checks an original message against an unblinded signature
  val checkSigner = new PSSSigner(new RSAEngine, new SHA1Digest, 20)
  checkSigner.init(false, public)
  checkSigner.update(message, 0, message.length)
  checkSigner.verifySignature(unblindedMessageSignature)  //> res0: Boolean = false, why false?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read up on using blind signatures. You cannot use PSS after blinding. The blinding property is only maintained if you directly perform modular exponentiation (raw RSA signature) over the result after blinding. This is very well explained in the RSA part of [the Wikipedia article about blind signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature).

Furthermore, you should probably feed the hash over your message `"hello there"` instead of the message itself. This is also mentioned in the Wiki article mentioned before.

Comment: And remember, hashes and padding schemes based on them are *one way*, which meant that I immediately knew what was wrong, even though I never used blinding myself. Good question though.